# How do I remove white outline around my sprite?

Tags: javascript, html, sprite

I'm making a simple HTML5 game.

I had a sprite. I removed the background from this sprite using the "transparent background" option in Photofiltre. I do not have any other photo editing software.

I managed to remove the background from the sprite. Unfortunately, my sprite has a whitish outline around the figure. This outline is especially noticeable when my sprite is placed over dark backgrounds on the web page. 
[white border around sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE0cM.png)

I was wondering how other people deal with this problem?Thanks!

Comment: Teaching you how to use your image editing software isn't really a programming problem.

Comment: looks to be a problem with your sprite, not Javascript. Whatever was used to make the BG transparent missed some pixels.

Answer (score -1):

You just missed that there is more than black and white...

Check the "radius" of the selection when making a color transparent, since the border of your sprite is not as hard the selection has does not have to be as hard.